# Looking for interactive SVG map script

Tags: javascript, svg, maps, interactive

I spent a lot of time looking for JS script for interactive svg maps.
I already found https://imagemappro.com/demo-mall/ and https://mapplic.com/maps/world?location=de. Those two look good and work well. But both of them are using JQ.
I don't want to include JQ to one page, one time use, If possible.

Basically I'm looking for a script that (does not matter if paid):

- Have a good API that allows me to select SVG elements and zoom into it etc.
- Allow to click into the element and display a popup on top of it with some content.
- Responsive and mobile friendly.
- Support Drag, zoom.
- NO JQ dependency.
- Have to support custom SVG.
- Allow me to link into an area, or some API hook that allows it.

Thanks for any sugestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mm, tough question. With [D3.js library](https://d3js.org/) you can do all that but it will require some learning to properly script it.

If you have WordPress then probably easier map plugin than Mapplic (that I still like most) is [MapSVG](https://mapsvg.com/). They offer world maps for free (with named country shapes e.g they have IDs) that you can use without buying MapSVG etc.

Other than that Google and GitHub search would give you various options, this library appears to be widely used (and you can have links in the SVG):

https://github.com/bumbu/svg-pan-zoom

Comment: Thanks.

I'm using NUXT for the project, and this map will be only one place, and that is the reason why I would like to avoid add jQuery to only one usage one place :)

Comment: Well, hope I have help a little. D3.js seems to be the right choice and is used with any framework you imagine (Node, React etc). This relatively simple example though being geo map can give you a hint what you need (instead of a geo map and all those projections - like Mercator - of course a custom SVG can be used). https://stackoverflow.com/a/64321700/2103539